# Disable HTML cache for development

Tags: caching

I am currently making code changes to a view rendering in Sitecore, and when a deploy these changes to my local environment, they were not visible. I realized that the rendering was marked as Cacheable, so I was seeing a previously cached version.

[image: Rendering Caching Settings]

Besides unchecking Cacheable on the renderings I'm currently working on, what would be the best way to disable HTML caching for development?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I typically disable caching for my local environment by setting the HTML cache lifetime to 1 second using the following config patch:

```xml
<setting name="Caching.HtmlLifetime">
  <patch:attribute name="value">00:00:01</patch:attribute>
</setting>
```

To make this specific to your local environment, you can patch it in using a [configuration transforms](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465318(v=vs.100).aspx) or using a tool like [Slow Cheetah](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/69023d00-a4f9-4a34-a6cd-7e854ba318b5)

Comment: While the rest of the answers are great, I'm choosing this one because it's specific (only affects HTML caching) and easy to implement in a multi-site solution.

Comment: In my opinion not the correct answer, as it affects the complete environment. The answer by disabling cacheHTML=false in the site node, is better, as it disables the cache for a specific site.

Comment: @BasLijten for me, that is a positive. This is for local development, and I do not want to disable cache for specific sites. In some cases, I may have 30+ site definitions.

Comment: @DerekHunziker ok, cool, fully understand!

Comment: I agree with Bas Lijten, this HtmlLifetime setting will not solve but create performance issues as Sitecore will create and destroy caches frequently, means it's actually not disabling Html Cache. For disabling cache, you should use cacheHtml=false.

Also, for multisite, you should not disable html cache, rather clear site-specific html cache based on publishing.

Comment: @YogeshPatel what performance issues are you referring to? This is for local development only. For multi site, I do in fact want HTML cache cleared automatically, not based on publishing.

Comment: @DerekHunziker Yeah, for development environment, it should be fine as it's a workaround, not the solution, so wanted to highlight! Also, we can disable cache for selected or all sites as well.

Comment: Yes, the question was focused on what to do in a development situation and not the best way to disable caching in production.

Comment: Also ensure iis level user and kernel cache is not enabled.

Answer (score 18):

You can turn cache off at the site level in the site definition in configuration:

```xml
<site name="website" enableTracking="true" virtualFolder="/" physicalFolder="/" rootPath="/sitecore/content" startItem="/home" database="web" domain="extranet" allowDebug="true" cacheHtml="true" htmlCacheSize="50MB" registryCacheSize="0" viewStateCacheSize="0" xslCacheSize="25MB" filteredItemsCacheSize="10MB" enablePreview="true" enableWebEdit="true" enableDebugger="true" disableClientData="false" cacheRenderingParameters="true" renderingParametersCacheSize="10MB" />
```

Simply make sure "cacheHtml" is set to "false".

Answer (score 10):

I typically do what you're doing and set all the renderings I want cached to be cacheable. However, for my local development, I will set `cacheHtml` to `false` on the site definition.

```xml
 <configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
   <sitecore>
     <sites>
        <site name="mySite" patch:before="site[@name='website']"
          ...
          cacheHtml="false"            
         />
      ...
```

Comment: This is my preferred method too. Typically I will have a configuration file that is for development environments only (i.e. not deployed) that overrides the default site definition to patch this attribute.

Answer (score 4):

Looking for `Caching.Enable` in your `web.config`. You can change it to false via a patch, transform, etc.

Comment: Correction -- It's Caching.Enabled

Comment: This will disable ALL Sitecore caches. Whilst this will include the HTML cache I'd consider it overkill for this siutation when there are means to just disable the HTML caching.