# Html.RenderFormScripts not loading scripts for sitecore CD when using with Rendering variants

Tags: sxa, sitecore-forms

In an sxa site, I have a custom sxa component with a placeholder item to load the form.
[image]
In the page using this component, I have added a `'Sitecore form Wrapper'=>'Mvc Form'` component using experience editor.
The layout file has `@Html.RenderFormScripts()` just before closing the body tag.

The form works fine in CM servers and Local instances.

Here is the issue Im facing.

When I load the page from CD server for the first time after publishing anything, the form loads fine and from the view-source: I can see the form related scripts are added to the page.
[image]

But when I do a page refresh, page does not load those scripts and form functionalities(like ajax, recaptcha, etc) are not working and when I check the view-source: these scripts are missing.
[image]

I tried to add a mvc form directly to the page without any rendering variant and its working but inside a rendering variant this issue I'm facing.

The form is very simple with just a text box
[image]

What might be the issue here.

Sitecore Version: 9.3 with SXA

Comment: Have you added caching to either the `Sitecore form Wrapper` or `Mvc Form` components for your site?

Comment: No caching added to the components, also without rending variant its working fine

Comment: This is likely a caching issue, either directly on the forms wrapper component or a parent component. You can verify by [disabling caching](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/q/42/135) and checking again.

Comment: @jammykam - thanks, Checked by disabling cache for the parent component working, dont understand why its causing this issue. We are using cdn and I tried clearing that cache but issue arise again if I enable caching.